# How to connect to Google Kubernetes engine with Kubernetes Python client

Tags: python, authentication, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm using Kubernetes Python client to manage my local Kubernetes cluster:

```
from kubernetes import client, config


config = client.Configuration()
config.host = "http://local_master_node:8080"
client.Configuration.set_default(config)
print(client.CoreV1Api().v1.list_node())
```

Everything works fine until I need to connect to a project on Google Cloud Kubernetes Engine using the key file provided by customer owning the project from Google like:

```
{
    "type": "...",
    "project_id": "...",
    "private_key_id": "...",
    "private_key": "...",
    "client_email": "...",
    "client_id": "...",
    "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
    "token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
    "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
    "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/..."
}
```

I'm trying to load it (probably doing it in wrong way):

```
os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = os.path.abspath('credentials.json')
config.load_incluster_config()
```

But this code raises an exception  `kubernetes.config.config_exception.ConfigException: Service host/port is not set.`

The questions are:

1. **How to provide Google credentials for Kubernetes Python client properly?**
2. **If I am on the right track then where can I find the host/port for using with Google Cloud?**

Some snippets will be appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally, I myself found the solution.

First, you need to get Kubernetes configuration file. So, go to Google Cloud Platform `Kubernetes Engine` panel. Select cluster you want to connect and press the `connect` button. Select `Run in Cloud Shell` and after you have logged into the shell type suggested string like:

```
$ gcloud container clusters get-credentials ...
```

Then you can find in `~/.kube` folder the configuration file. Save its content to a yaml-file which you should feed to `kubernetes.config.load_kube_config` function:

```
os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = os.path.abspath('credentials.json')
config.load_kube_config(os.path.abspath('config.yaml'))
```