# Connecting to Milvus Database through Google Kubernetes Engine and Python

Tags: python, authentication, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I’m looking to connect to a [Milvus database](https://milvus.io/docs/v2.0.0) I deployed on Google Kubernetes Engine.

I am running into an error in the last line of the script. I'm running the script locally.

Here's the process I followed to set up the GKE cluster: (https://milvus.io/docs/v2.0.0/gcp.md)

Here is [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52890728/how-to-connect-to-google-kubernetes-engine-with-kubernetes-python-client) I'm drawing from

Any thoughts on what I'm missing?

```
import os
from pymilvus import connections
from kubernetes import client, config

My_Kubernetes_IP = 'XX.XXX.XX.XX'

# Authenticate with GCP credentials
os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = os.path.abspath('credentials.json')

# load milvus config file and connect to GKE instance 
config = client.Configuration(os.path.abspath('milvus/config.yaml'))
config.host = f'https://{My_Kubernetes_IP}:19530'
client.Configuration.set_default(config)

## connect to milvus
milvus_ip = 'xx.xxx.xx.xx'
connections.connect(host=milvus_ip, port= '19530')
```

Error:

BaseException: <BaseException: (code=2, message=Fail connecting to server on xx.xxx.xx.xx:19530. Timeout)>

Answer (score 0):

If you want to connect to the Milvus in the k8s cluster by ip+port, you may need to forward your local port 19530 to the Milvus service. Use a command like the following:

$ kubectl port-forward service/my-release-milvus 19530

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked where your milvus external IP is?

Follow the instructions by the documentation you should use `kubectl get services` to check which external IP is allocated for the milvus.